# Need to create custom serializer / deserializer for text to object and vice versa

Tags: c#

I have a text data that I need to convert into the class object using deserialization and also need to get its text format when serializing it.

The text data is in following format:

```
FORM "Employee"
BEGIN
    SIZE 628, 800
    LANGUAGE 2052

    FIELD "FirstName"
    BEGIN
        POSITION 0, 0
        SIZE 144, 35
        FONT "Arial"
        POINTSIZE 20
        VALUE "RAM"        
    END
    XFSFIELD "LastName"
    BEGIN
        POSITION 0, 0
        SIZE 144, 35
        FONT "Arial"
        POINTSIZE 20
        VALUE "SHARMA"
    END
END
```

I create a class for storing this data

```
    public class Form
    {
        public string NAME { get; set; }    
        public ClsSize SIZE { get; set; }    
        public string ID { get; set; }    
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public ClsPosition POSITION { get; set; }
        public ClsSize SIZE { get; set; }
        public string FONT { get; set; }
        public int POINTSIZE { get; set; }
        public string VALUE { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClsSize
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClsPosition
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
    }
```

So I need to serialize and deserialize that text to class object and vice versa, so how to implement the custom serialization for this?

Comment: Do you have format name? Depending on the variability you can use different approaches. The simplest one would be some kind of state machine which will traverse the lines and analyze them. Alternatively you can go with full blown "write your language" approach with lexers, parsers and so on.